# Como acceder a web site con ip publica con xampp

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp, windows-server, vps

Tengo instalado xampp en un VPS con Windows Server 2012. En xampp tengo un sitio web hecho con wordpress multisite. Tengo todo configurado correctamente, los puertos, el firewall, etc.

cuando ingreso la ip publica abre localhost/dashboard (todo bien hasta ahi) pero no he logrado enlazar la ip publica del VPS al sitio web que tengo (esta en la ruta:xampp/htdocs/misitio ) de modo que para cuando ingrese la ip publica desde cualquier otro dispositivo o red pueda acceder y también cuando quiera apuntar un dominio hacia la ip publica.

Comment: Debes actualizar tu Virtual Host acá te dejo una web que conseguí https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/configurar-virtual-hosts-apache-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Ve a Tu panel de control XAMPP
2. Haga clic en apache > configuración > Apache (httpd.conf)
3. Busque ServerName localhost: 80 y reemplácelo con `su IP publica: 80`
4. Haga clic en apache > configuración > httpd-vhosts.conf

`DocumentRoot "ruta:/xampp/htdocs/misitio"`

Agregas también

```
<Directory "ruta:/xampp/htdocs/misitio">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Final todo sería así

Comment: Gracias, al final pude resolver crear  website distintas para cada site dentro de wordpress multisite, al parecer la estrutura de worpdpress multisite me estaba dando ese prioblema.

Comment: @RicardoOrtega si te ha ayudado está repuesta, Por favor marcas como respuesta aceptada. !Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Esa me ha servido cientos de veces.

```html
#<VirtualHost *:80>  
    #ServerAdmin EJEMPLO@icloud.com
    #DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress"
    #ServerName 45.20.221.117
    #ServerAlias  www.45.20.221.117
    #ErrorLog "logs/EJEMPLO.dns2go.info-error.log"
    #CustomLog "logs/EJEMPLO.dns2go.info-access.log" common
#</VirtualHost>
```